# Discussion board: Notifications on top level

Tags: alert, discussion-board

I can obviously set notifications ("Alert me") for a particular posting.

However, if I want to get notified on any activity on the discussion board (e.g. new posts created) what would the recommend way be? I somehow have the feeling I am overlooking something here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Ribbon, under List > Alert me > Set alert on this list, you can set alerts when new items are added

[image]

Comment: I knew it :) Many thanks for opening my (obviously tightly closed) eyes!